# Can I download a file from URL to a server using javascript\php

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas

Here's my dilemma:
I want users to be able to load images to a canvas by providing a URL to the image (it can be any image file). I can do this, but adding the image directly from a URL prevents the canvas from being exported to a file.
so what I want to do it create a temporary copy on the server, and be able to get the path to it as a javascript var....
is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always attempt to have your server make an http request for that url, but there are several issues:

1. You will need to check to make sure the http request does not resolve internally; that is, only external sites should be allowed, otherwise you've just made a security hole for your network by allowing things that once could only be seen internally now accessible externally if one knows the right path.
2. There's no guarantee that the server you're pulling the image from will oblige your request.  They may have checks to see that the image is being referred to from an "authorized" (using the term loosely here) page, or they may deny certain user agent strings, or assert that some cookie is set, or some combination of the above.
3. You may need to implement some sort of checks to make sure the user is authorized to request your server to make the request of the url and that the returned content is indeed some image type, otherwise you've just made a semi functional proxy that might be abused (especially if you're concerned about cross site scripting attacks to your website;) and ideally you also don't want to allow your users to over-utilize your server for no real purpose.

Once you get past issues #1 and #3, strictly speaking, there's no reason the file has to be actually copied to your server, but usage might be more stable if you did save it to the server.  But if you are going to save it, then there's other issues.

1. How would you limit access to the files for the current user?
2. What's your clean-up strategy?
3. Do the requests need to utilize some sort of client side caching for reasonable performance?  How exactly would the files be served?  What would the files be named?
4. What if the files are copyrighted, or worse, *illegal*?

You don't have to have all these questions in mind to implement a basic solution, of course, but I do think it's wise to consider at least once.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can do this via [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).